# How to fix the label and a viewpoint for a 3d surface plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have plotted a data, now I want to label this plot, x-axis as K1, y as K2, z as b. And I also I want to fix the viewpoint, right now I am doing it manually is there means to just input the view angle. and lastly I am planning to put this in a paper, I have to put this in a high-quality picture in proper labeling, font size, etc. Mathematica always refers to SciDraw, but I don't know how to use that. below is my code.

```
kt = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
   800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
   70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
betas = {{10.9036, 10.9038, 10.9041, 10.9046, 10.9051, 10.9057, 
    10.9062, 10.9102, 10.9168, 10.93, 10.956, 10.9815, 11.0065, 
    11.0311, 11.0553, 11.1023, 11.1476, 11.3518, 11.6683, 11.791, 
    12.1865, 12.3876, 12.504, 12.6296, 12.695, 12.7805, 12.8149, 
    12.887, 12.8949, 12.895}, {10.9038, 10.9041, 10.9044, 10.9049, 
    10.9054, 10.906, 10.9065, 10.9105, 10.9171, 10.9303, 10.9562, 
    10.9817, 11.0068, 11.0314, 11.0555, 11.1025, 11.1479, 11.3521, 
    11.6685, 11.7912, 12.1866, 12.3877, 12.5041, 12.6296, 12.695, 
    12.7806, 12.815, 12.887, 12.8949, 12.895}, {10.9041, 10.9044, 
    10.9046, 10.9052, 10.9057, 10.9062, 10.9068, 10.9108, 10.9174, 
    10.9306, 10.9565, 10.982, 11.0071, 11.0316, 11.0558, 11.1028, 
    11.1481, 11.3523, 11.6686, 11.7913, 12.1867, 12.3878, 12.5041, 
    12.6297, 12.695, 12.7806, 12.815, 12.887, 12.8949, 
    12.895}, {10.9047, 10.9049, 10.9052, 10.9057, 10.9063, 10.9068, 
    10.9073, 10.9113, 10.9179, 10.9311, 10.9571, 10.9826, 11.0076, 
    11.0322, 11.0563, 11.1033, 11.1486, 11.3527, 11.669, 11.7917, 
    12.1869, 12.3879, 12.5042, 12.6297, 12.6951, 12.7806, 12.815, 
    12.8871, 12.8949, 12.895}, {10.9052, 10.9055, 10.9058, 10.9063, 
    10.9068, 10.9074, 10.9079, 10.9119, 10.9185, 10.9317, 10.9576, 
    10.9831, 11.0081, 11.0327, 11.0568, 11.1038, 11.1491, 11.3532, 
    11.6693, 11.792, 12.1871, 12.3881, 12.5043, 12.6298, 12.6952, 
    12.7807, 12.8151, 12.8871, 12.895, 12.895}, {10.9058, 10.906, 
    10.9063, 10.9068, 10.9074, 10.9079, 10.9084, 10.9124, 10.9191, 
    10.9322, 10.9582, 10.9836, 11.0086, 11.0332, 11.0573, 11.1043, 
    11.1496, 11.3536, 11.6697, 11.7923, 12.1873, 12.3882, 12.5045, 
    12.6299, 12.6952, 12.7807, 12.8151, 12.8871, 12.895, 
    12.8951}, {10.9063, 10.9066, 10.9069, 10.9074, 10.9079, 10.9085, 
    10.909, 10.913, 10.9196, 10.9328, 10.9587, 10.9842, 11.0092, 
    11.0337, 11.0579, 11.1048, 11.1501, 11.3541, 11.6701, 11.7926, 
    12.1875, 12.3884, 12.5046, 12.63, 12.6953, 12.7808, 12.8151, 
    12.8871, 12.895, 12.8951}, {10.9105, 10.9108, 10.9111, 10.9116, 
    10.9121, 10.9127, 10.9132, 10.9172, 10.9238, 10.9369, 10.9628, 
    10.9882, 11.0132, 11.0377, 11.0618, 11.1086, 11.1538, 11.3574, 
    11.6727, 11.795, 12.189, 12.3895, 12.5054, 12.6306, 12.6958, 
    12.7811, 12.8154, 12.8873, 12.8952, 12.8953}, {10.9175, 10.9177, 
    10.918, 10.9185, 10.9191, 10.9196, 10.9201, 10.9241, 10.9307, 
    10.9438, 10.9696, 10.9949, 11.0198, 11.0442, 11.0682, 11.1149, 
    11.16, 11.3628, 11.6771, 11.799, 12.1916, 12.3913, 12.5068, 
    12.6316, 12.6966, 12.7817, 12.8159, 12.8877, 12.8955, 
    12.8956}, {10.9313, 10.9315, 10.9318, 10.9323, 10.9329, 10.9334, 
    10.9339, 10.9379, 10.9444, 10.9574, 10.983, 11.0082, 11.0329, 
    11.0572, 11.081, 11.1275, 11.1722, 11.3738, 11.6859, 11.8069, 
    12.1966, 12.3949, 12.5096, 12.6336, 12.6982, 12.7828, 12.8169, 
    12.8883, 12.8961, 12.8962}, {10.9585, 10.9588, 10.959, 10.9595, 
    10.9601, 10.9606, 10.9611, 10.965, 10.9715, 10.9843, 11.0096, 
    11.0344, 11.0589, 11.0828, 11.1064, 11.1522, 11.1964, 11.3953, 
    11.7032, 11.8225, 12.2066, 12.402, 12.5151, 12.6375, 12.7013, 
    12.7851, 12.8188, 12.8896, 12.8974, 12.8974}, {10.9852, 10.9855, 
    10.9858, 10.9863, 10.9868, 10.9873, 10.9878, 10.9916, 10.998, 
    11.0107, 11.0357, 11.0602, 11.0843, 11.108, 11.1312, 11.1764, 
    11.2201, 11.4164, 11.7202, 11.8378, 12.2164, 12.4089, 12.5205, 
    12.6413, 12.7044, 12.7873, 12.8207, 12.8909, 12.8986, 
    12.8987}, {11.0115, 11.0117, 11.012, 11.0125, 11.013, 11.0135, 
    11.014, 11.0178, 11.0241, 11.0366, 11.0613, 11.0855, 11.1093, 
    11.1327, 11.1556, 11.2002, 11.2433, 11.4371, 11.7368, 11.8528, 
    12.2259, 12.4158, 12.5259, 12.6451, 12.7075, 12.7895, 12.8226, 
    12.8922, 12.8998, 12.8999}, {11.0373, 11.0375, 11.0378, 11.0383, 
    11.0388, 11.0393, 11.0398, 11.0435, 11.0497, 11.0621, 11.0864, 
    11.1104, 11.1338, 11.1569, 11.1796, 11.2236, 11.2662, 11.4574, 
    11.7531, 11.8675, 12.2353, 12.4225, 12.5311, 12.6488, 12.7105, 
    12.7916, 12.8244, 12.8934, 12.901, 12.9011}, {11.0626, 11.0628, 
    11.0631, 11.0636, 11.0641, 11.0646, 11.0651, 11.0688, 11.0749, 
    11.0871, 11.1111, 11.1348, 11.1579, 11.1807, 11.2031, 11.2466, 
    11.2886, 11.4774, 11.7691, 11.882, 12.2445, 12.429, 12.5362, 
    12.6525, 12.7134, 12.7937, 12.8262, 12.8946, 12.9021, 
    12.9022}, {11.1119, 11.1121, 11.1123, 11.1128, 11.1133, 11.1138, 
    11.1143, 11.1179, 11.1239, 11.1358, 11.1592, 11.1822, 11.2049, 
    11.2271, 11.2489, 11.2913, 11.3322, 11.5162, 11.8002, 11.91, 
    12.2624, 12.4418, 12.5461, 12.6596, 12.7192, 12.7978, 12.8297, 
    12.897, 12.9044, 12.9045}, {11.1594, 11.1596, 11.1599, 11.1603, 
    11.1608, 11.1613, 11.1618, 11.1653, 11.1711, 11.1827, 11.2056, 
    11.2281, 11.2501, 11.2718, 11.293, 11.3344, 11.3743, 11.5536, 
    11.8302, 11.937, 12.2796, 12.4541, 12.5557, 12.6665, 12.7248, 
    12.8019, 12.8332, 12.8994, 12.9067, 12.9068}, {11.3734, 11.3736, 
    11.3738, 11.3742, 11.3746, 11.375, 11.3755, 11.3786, 11.3838, 
    11.394, 11.4143, 11.4342, 11.4537, 11.4728, 11.4916, 11.5282, 
    11.5635, 11.7215, 11.9641, 12.0574, 12.3563, 12.5092, 12.5989, 
    12.6976, 12.7501, 12.8202, 12.8489, 12.9102, 12.917, 
    12.9171}, {11.7047, 11.7048, 11.705, 11.7053, 11.7057, 11.706, 
    11.7063, 11.7088, 11.7129, 11.7211, 11.7371, 11.7529, 11.7683, 
    11.7835, 11.7983, 11.8272, 11.855, 11.9792, 12.1684, 12.2409, 
    12.4736, 12.5943, 12.6664, 12.7471, 12.7907, 12.8501, 12.8748, 
    12.9283, 12.9343, 12.9344}, {11.833, 11.8331, 11.8333, 11.8336, 
    11.8339, 11.8342, 11.8345, 11.8367, 11.8404, 11.8476, 11.862, 
    11.8761, 11.8899, 11.9035, 11.9168, 11.9426, 11.9674, 12.0782, 
    12.2467, 12.3112, 12.519, 12.6277, 12.6931, 12.7669, 12.8072, 
    12.8624, 12.8855, 12.9359, 12.9416, 12.9416}, {12.2442, 12.2443, 
    12.2444, 12.2446, 12.2447, 12.2449, 12.2451, 12.2465, 12.2487, 
    12.2532, 12.262, 12.2706, 12.2791, 12.2874, 12.2955, 12.3113, 
    12.3264, 12.394, 12.4972, 12.537, 12.6683, 12.7399, 12.7844, 
    12.8364, 12.8657, 12.9069, 12.9246, 12.9642, 12.9688, 
    12.9688}, {12.451, 12.4511, 12.4511, 12.4513, 12.4514, 12.4515, 
    12.4516, 12.4526, 12.4541, 12.4572, 12.4632, 12.4691, 12.475, 
    12.4807, 12.4862, 12.4971, 12.5075, 12.5542, 12.6263, 12.6545, 
    12.7494, 12.803, 12.8371, 12.8777, 12.9011, 12.9346, 12.9493, 
    12.9826, 12.9865, 12.9866}, {12.5695, 12.5695, 12.5695, 12.5696, 
    12.5697, 12.5698, 12.5699, 12.5706, 12.5718, 12.5741, 12.5786, 
    12.5831, 12.5875, 12.5918, 12.596, 12.6042, 12.6121, 12.6475, 
    12.7029, 12.7248, 12.7997, 12.843, 12.871, 12.905, 12.9247, 
    12.9535, 12.9662, 12.9955, 12.999, 12.999}, {12.696, 12.6961, 
    12.6961, 12.6962, 12.6962, 12.6963, 12.6964, 12.6968, 12.6976, 
    12.6992, 12.7023, 12.7053, 12.7083, 12.7112, 12.714, 12.7196, 
    12.725, 12.7495, 12.7882, 12.8037, 12.8581, 12.8906, 12.912, 
    12.9385, 12.9542, 12.9775, 12.9879, 13.0123, 13.0152, 
    13.0153}, {12.7614, 12.7614, 12.7614, 12.7615, 12.7615, 12.7616, 
    12.7616, 12.762, 12.7626, 12.7638, 12.7662, 12.7686, 12.7709, 
    12.7732, 12.7754, 12.7798, 12.784, 12.8033, 12.8341, 12.8465, 
    12.8909, 12.9178, 12.9358, 12.9583, 12.9718, 12.992, 13.0012, 
    13.0228, 13.0254, 13.0254}, {12.8463, 12.8463, 12.8463, 12.8463, 
    12.8464, 12.8464, 12.8464, 12.8467, 12.8471, 12.8479, 12.8495, 
    12.8511, 12.8527, 12.8542, 12.8557, 12.8587, 12.8616, 12.8747, 
    12.8961, 12.9049, 12.9368, 12.9567, 12.9702, 12.9875, 12.9981, 
    13.0141, 13.0214, 13.039, 13.0412, 13.0412}, {12.8802, 12.8802, 
    12.8802, 12.8802, 12.8803, 12.8803, 12.8803, 12.8805, 12.8809, 
    12.8815, 12.8829, 12.8842, 12.8855, 12.8868, 12.888, 12.8905, 
    12.8929, 12.9038, 12.9218, 12.9292, 12.9564, 12.9736, 12.9854, 
    13.0006, 13.0099, 13.0242, 13.0307, 13.0467, 13.0486, 
    13.0486}, {12.9508, 12.9508, 12.9508, 12.9509, 12.9509, 12.9509, 
    12.9509, 12.951, 12.9512, 12.9517, 12.9525, 12.9533, 12.9541, 
    12.9549, 12.9557, 12.9572, 12.9587, 12.9657, 12.9772, 12.9821, 
    13.0002, 13.012, 13.0202, 13.031, 13.0378, 13.0483, 13.0532, 
    13.0653, 13.0668, 13.0668}, {12.9585, 12.9585, 12.9585, 12.9585, 
    12.9586, 12.9586, 12.9586, 12.9587, 12.9589, 12.9593, 12.9601, 
    12.9609, 12.9616, 12.9624, 12.9631, 12.9646, 12.966, 12.9725, 
    12.9834, 12.988, 13.0052, 13.0164, 13.0243, 13.0346, 13.0411, 
    13.0512, 13.0559, 13.0676, 13.0691, 13.0691}, {12.9586, 12.9586, 
    12.9586, 12.9586, 12.9586, 12.9586, 12.9587, 12.9588, 12.959, 
    12.9594, 12.9602, 12.9609, 12.9617, 12.9624, 12.9632, 12.9646, 
    12.9661, 12.9726, 12.9835, 12.9881, 13.0053, 13.0165, 13.0243, 
    13.0347, 13.0411, 13.0512, 13.056, 13.0676, 13.0691, 13.0691}};
data = Flatten[
   Table[{Log[kt[[i]]], Log[kt[[j]]], betas[[i, j]]}, {i, 30}, {j, 
     30}], 1];
ListPlot3D[data]
```

Comment: `AxesLabel` and `ViewAngle`?

Comment: Yes I tried both, I am not getting the desired result. for example axes label function does not work like how frame label works. And I don't know frame label is not working for 3D plots. And I don't want the surface plot fitted inside a box , how to remove that?

Comment: Please consult the "Options" section of the documentation of `ListPlot3D`. For example, `Boxed -> False` removes the box.

Comment: It is not clear which point of view you want to choose from which side?

Comment: `data = Flatten[
   Table[{kt[[i]], kt[[j]], betas[[i, j]]}, {i, 30}, {j, 30}], 1];
ListPointPlot3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]`  or `ListPlot3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[data, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
     AxesLabel -> {"K1", "K2", "b"}]
```

[image: fig1]

```
{ListPlot3D[data, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  AxesLabel -> {"lnK1", "lnK2", "b"}, ViewPoint -> {0, -2., 0}], 
 ListPlot3D[data, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  AxesLabel -> {"lnK1", "lnK2", "b"}, ViewPoint -> {0, -2., 1/2}], 
 ListPlot3D[data, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  AxesLabel -> {"lnK1", "lnK2", "b"}, ViewPoint -> {0, -2., 1/2}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: The x and y - axis is in log scale, but the plot showing 0, 10 ,20 how to change that?. and also how to change the angle so that  I can view the lowest surface front side

Comment: @acoustics See update.